# My pip isn't installing my packages correctly

Tags: python-2.7

It's messing all my installation up all of a sudden.

I've installed it using `pip BeautifulSoup4` for example

It keeps installing- when I use python and import it; it doesn't import it properly.

However; somehow my requests works. I think I messed up my PATH variable.

```
>>> import sys
>>> print '\n'.join(sys.path)

/usr/local/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/Library/python2.7/site-packages
/Library/python2.7/site-packages/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Library/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Users/biplovdahal/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
/Users/biplovdahal/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

^ How would I set my pip to listen to a specific site-package and keep installing my future modules in that one site-packages. I don't want it mixed up anymore. I'd  like to also get rid of all the permission problem as possible so I can safely install my package and use it.

Comment: You can use pip specific which is associated to python 2.7. Try using `pip2.7 package-name`

Comment: -bash: pip2.7: command not found

Answer (score -1):

You can call pip by prefixing python path like this

```
 /usr/local/bin/python pip install <package name>
```

The above command wiill place site-packages in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` folder . if you want to change it to install to someother library , you change the python path  in the `pip` command

Comment: I got -bash: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory

Comment: @Dilli : You have to replace it with the python path where its installed in your machine . You can get it using `which python` . In my machine its `/usr/local/bin/python `

Comment: I tried it and it gives me /usr/bin/python: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: /usr/local/bin/pip @Sandeep Lade

Comment: so use `<ur python path> <ur pip path> <install/upgrade> <packagename>`

Comment: Is there a way for me to set it up so I can just do pip install ?

Comment: /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/pip install BeautifulSoup4 I did that and ran python in command line and it still said No module named BeautifulSoup4. I think my path directory are all messed up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165449/discussion-between-dilli-and-sandeep-lade).